# Do something when clicking on class

Tags: javascript, class, onclick, click

I am trying to run a function when user clicks on a class.

Here is a fiddle with a similar setup.  Except that I am not using buttons in the my code.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/keturp/0wssdsn1/)

```
document.querySelectorAll('.menu').onclick = function () { alert("test"); };
```

I've also tried using the getElementsByClassName, with the same results.  Is there something I am missing here?

*Note: I need to accomplish this without jQuery

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/keturp/0wssdsn1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`querySelectorAll` returns a list of elements, so you need to specify the one you want, in your case [`0]`:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.menu')[0].onclick = function () {
    alert("test");
};
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/0wssdsn1/1/)**

Comment: thanks i was able to accomplish with this answer.